# configuring cartodb for running on local machine

Tags: server, carto, configuration

How to  configure cartodb to run fully on local machine. I have setup a development version of cartodb. In this the tables are limited to 5, the disk space is limited and the view. Is these variables can be configured to be run on local server. I have looked the database.yml and app_config.yml. Is there any docs available for cartodb server configuration on  local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "run fully" you specifically mean increase max tables, disk quota, account type, etc., see the commented out parts at the bottom of [this script](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/script/create_dev_user):

```
# Update your quota to 10GB
echo "--- Updating quota to 10GB"
bundle exec rake cartodb:db:set_user_quota["${SUBDOMAIN}",10240]
if test $? -ne 0; then exit 1; fi

# Allow unlimited tables to be created
echo "--- Allowing unlimited tables creation"
bundle exec rake cartodb:db:set_unlimited_table_quota["${SUBDOMAIN}"]
if test $? -ne 0; then exit 1; fi

# Allow user to create private tables in addition to public
echo "--- Allowing private tables creation"
bundle exec rake \
 cartodb:db:set_user_private_tables_enabled["${SUBDOMAIN}",'true']
if test $? -ne 0; then exit 1; fi

# Set the account type
echo "--- Setting cartodb account type"
bundle exec rake \
 cartodb:db:set_user_account_type["${SUBDOMAIN}",'[DEDICATED]']
if test $? -ne 0; then exit 1; fi
```

Run as a shell script or just paste into your console from the cartodb directory. First make sure SUBDOMAIN is set, or hardcode here.

Comment: What about map views? I didn't find any command to increment that!

Comment: @galex according to [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cartodb/map$20views/cartodb/QrMflhohTAs/_IRxZXX35EUJ), map views are only enforced on commercial accounts. But you can still increase the limit with a query on the Rails app database (see config/database.yml): 
`update users set map_view_quota = 100000 where id = your_user_id;`

Comment: One addition since this was posted, you'll also want to increase your user limits:

`bundle exec rake cartodb:set_custom_limits_for_user["${SUBDOMAIN}",import_file_size,table_row_count,concurrent_imports]`

Comment: Thanks, do you have any equivalent for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

CartoDB can be installed on your own server. Just follow the tutorial at https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb